# Checkbox not evaluating to true even though it is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that has a register checkbox and a waitlist checkbox depending on some values I hide one of the checkboxes and display a star for some odd reason when I run my website one time it evaluates to true the next time i get some error saying

```
Checked The name 'Checked' does not exist in the current context
```

.aspx

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Register" ItemStyle-CssClass="template-center">
                        <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" runat="server"/>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStarRegister" runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wait List" ItemStyle-CssClass="template-center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWaitList" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStarWaitList" runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind

```
  if ((((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRegister")).Checked == true) || (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkWaitList")).Checked == true))
```

Comment: As i was typing this I think i found out since i am hiding and showing my checkboxes I think my if statement can not evaluate .Checked because the checkbox is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visible = false` will not render your control. Use `display:none` to hide your control. It will be available.

Edit:

Use css like

```
.hiddenelement
{
    display:none;
}
```

Apply this class on the checkbox you want to hide. like

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" runat="server" CssClass="hiddenelement"/>
```

The checkbox will be hidden but available in code behind.

Edit2:

```
if (true)
{
    chkRegister.CssClass = "displaynone";
}
else
{
   chkRegister.CssClass = chkRegister.CssClass.Replace("displaynone", "");
}
```

Comment: How do i use display:none in code behind? right now im using chkWaitlist.visible = false;

Comment: Sorry did not explain myself I am hiding my checkbox dynamically so will have to be on the gridviewrowdatabound event that I apply the css based on other conditions is this possible

Comment: @Tim If you want to hide it from code behind then add CssClass in RowDataBound. The checkbox will be hidden but available.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need the checkbox to be visible sometimes and hidden other based on criteria. I understand how to apply css to a control but not dynamically like if (number = 1) chkRegister.CSS = displaynone else chkRegister.CSS = display (something like that) sorry if i am not understanding you

Comment: Thanks I marked it as correct because technically it is but in my case it did not work applying css because my chkRegister is in a gridview and they are all named chkRegister. So once one gets the css applied to it then the checkbox does not show for any of the rows and I needed it to show for some rows and hide for others thanks for trying though